# All disk Utility Options Disabled

Tags: macos, mac, disk-utility

Last day my mac suddenly stooped working, i tried google and by pressing Command + R i landed into menu where globe appear and finally i can see reinstall mac os , disk utility and other options.

now when i try to reinstall OS it didn't show the drive there, and when i go to disk utility all the options there like erase, repair are disabled. if i go to File -> Open Disk Image in disk utility it opens the finder and i can see all the data in my hard drive.

now i am stuck not able to reinstall OS or go into os, not sure what to do.

anybody can help?

some of the images of utility disk

[image]Ybss6-5524m@A245874Gctas#
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The images of a Finder window showing a file system are a bit confusing. Are you getting that window in recovery mode? I didn't think that was possible/available.

Regardless the "Mac OS Base System" is the system that the Mac is booted from in Recovery mode, I believe. And you can't do anything with it, that is intentional, from Apple.

The fact that your HD is not visible indicates to me that your HD/SSD has died (Bereft of life, it rests in peace... [sorry]). It is *likely* that you need a new hd/ssd. It is possible, but not real likely, that something else (cable, connector, system board) is at fault but Mr. Occam and his Razor suggest that it's a bad drive and need to be replaced.

Time to take it in for diagnosis and repair.

Comment: if the hard is dead then why showing in "Open Disk Image", i think my volumes are locked and i need someway to unlock them, it's still showing me 2.0GB in which i believe it have the main OS of MAC

Comment: Likely the disk image that you are booted from in Recovery Mode.

Comment: ok but i didn't booted from external source but from internet recovery, when it booted it showed the globe and connects with internet to boot

Comment: That is the way Internet Recovery Mode works.